# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:

Tags: java, jdbc

I know this has been asked a hundred times and I think I have read all the posts and tried every variation of the solutions. I'm using NetBeans and new to it. I'm sure I'm just missing some small step because it seems like its just not seeing the driver that I added to the library. This is the first time I have tried to connect to a database so please be gentle.

```
try
       {        
        String host = "jdbc:sqlserver://Server:1433;Database";
        String uName = "User";
        String uPass = "Password";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);
        System.out.println("Your are connected to SQLServer 2014");
        }
        catch (SQLException err)
        {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
```

[image]

Comment: The driver isn't into the Path... Probably.

Comment: check this page: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html

Comment: From what I read adding it to the library in the newer versions should add it to the path.

Comment: do you think that if that was it, netbeans would maintain that page?

Comment: In your project under "Libraries", try removing the "C:\Program Files\..." *folder* and then add an entry for the *actual jar file* you want to use, e.g., "sqljdbc42.jar".

Comment: Thanks Gord that did the trick. Now I've got a new error The connection string contains a badly formed name or value.

Comment: @TECC - Have you seen [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url)? (Also, remember to "@ping" users on replies as I did at the beginning of this comment.)

Comment: @GordThompson - Thanks I didn't know about the ping. I have read that document about 3 times. I tried adding the instance but that still did not work. Its got to be something simple. is there a way to get more information out of the error. Like invalid database or incorrect user information?

Comment: @TECC - Try something like `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:49242;databaseName=myDb`

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks I got a much more descriptive error that I think I can use to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to register the jdbc driver class.

Call

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

before calling `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);`.

It will resolve the issue.

**UPDATE**

In documentation for new jdbc drivers it is declared that this step is not necessary. But in practical work, I have found that this step is required even for new drivers, otherwise you will get "No suitable driver found" error. This error occurs sometimes, for example it does not occur when you are making and running a console jar-application, but occurs when you have created and deployed a web-application.

So, I advise to register the jdbc driver class before getting the database connection via `DriverManager.getConnection()` call.

Comment: From what I have read this is no longer necessary and has been deprecated.

Comment: Yes, according to docs - it is not necessary. But in practice this step is required :)

Comment: Ok then I will give it a try. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: ok. Post the results of your checking here, please. I am sure it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Using `Class.forName` is not necessary in a lot of situations since Java 6; there are some exceptions (eg in web applications the different hierarchies of classloaders can make it necessary to explicitly load a driver), but in a 'normal' Java application this is not actually necessary.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In my _update_ section I mentioned this difference. But to avoid the _possible_ error, I recommend to register the jdbc driver class always.